# psql "invalid client_encoding" error on OS X, PostgreSQL 9.4.5

Tags: postgresql, configuration, postgresql-9.4, encoding, mac-os-x

I'm currently running a OS X Lion Server system which ships with a built-in and not-upgradable PostgreSQL version.
After years of usage I've finnaly decided to leave the built-in version and install an indipendent version. I disabled the built-in installation and downloaded the installer from EDB and followed the wizard. After many issues reguarding encoding and locales, I've finally managed how to setup a DB with no locale and UTF8 encoding. I issued the following command:

```
initdb -D /path/to/data --no-locale --encoding=UTF8
```

If I connect using pgAdminIII I get no problems. The command `show client_encoding;` displays `UNICODE` as the encoding used by pgAdminIII (the default installation gave me a `SQL_ASCII` encoding and that's why I run the `initdb` command).

The problem is that I'm not able to connect to PostgreSQL using `psql`. Whatever I pass to it, I get the following error:

```
psql: invalid connection option "client_encoding"
```

I've searched through the Internet but found nothing that solves my problem (for example issuing `env PGCLIENTENCODING=UTF8` and adding `client_encoding=UTF8` to `postgresql.conf`).

`otool -L /Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/psql` returns:

```
/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/psql:
    @loader_path/../lib/libpq.5.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.7.0)
    @loader_path/../lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    @loader_path/../lib/libedit.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.48.0)
    /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 169.3.0)
```

Anyone can help me to figure it out?

Many thanks to all
 Pietro

### UPDATE

I forgot to logout and then login after editing the bash profile. The suggestion made by Daniel Vérité was right. I just edited the `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` env variable in `/etc/profile` in order to make it visible at a global level and not only from the interactive shell.

I added the following line to `/etc/profile`:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH='/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/lib'
```

I hope this helps others.

Daniel, Thank you a lot

Comment: It could be that you're running the pre-installed `psql` instead of the new one. Invoke commands with their full paths to be sure.

Comment: @DanielVérité I cleaned up the original binaries in /usr/bin and updated the symlink to the new Postgres' binaries path, so I'm sure to invoke the 9.4.5 installation.

Comment: So the next step would be to do do the same with libpq. Apparently the new psql links dynamically to the old libpq. In Unix this can be dealt with the help of `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. Not sure about MacOS.

Comment: How can I achieve this? `env LD_LIBRARY_PATH=...` or is there a more robust way?

Comment: First check if that's the problem. It looks that `otool -L /path/to/psql` would be able to tell.

Comment: I've just added the output to the original answer.

Comment: So what's the exact `psql` command line that fails?

Comment: Any `psql` invocation (parameters doesn't seem to affect `psql` output). It prints out `psql: invalid connection option "client_encoding"` and exits. I tried to run it from various users (administrator user, sudoer, postgres) but nothing changes.

Comment: This error comes from `libpq`. As this option was added in 2011, it makes sense if you're using a newer psql with an older libpq. Setting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` to `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/lib` could work, or if not google around for other tweaks to the same effect.

Comment: I tried setting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` in different ways but it gives `psql` the same error. I've found that launching `psql` from within `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin` or via `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/lib/psql` works. This probably has to do with relative paths. Actually if I simply execute the `psql` command from the shell it executes `/usr/bin/psql` which is a symbolic link to `/Library/PostgreSQL/9.4/bin/psql`. Any ideas?

Comment: @DanielVérité your suggestion was correct. I've updated the answer with your solution. If you want, create an answer and I'll accept it ;) Thank you again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`client_encoding` is a libpq connection option that was added circa 2011 and will not be recognized by older versions.

The error:

> psql: invalid connection option "client_encoding"

comes from dynamically linking a newer `psql` with an older `libpq`, for instance the one that ships with the system.

On Mac OS X, this can be worked around by setting `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` (the equivalent of linux's `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`) to the path of the newer PostgreSQL installation.

Per comments and update, it's confirmed to work when setting this variable globally in `/etc/profile`